# Grep in perl never seems to work for me

Tags: regex, perl

I have a simple script that reads and list file from a directory.
But I don't want to list hidden files, files with a " . " in front.

So I've tried using the *grep* function to do this, but it returns nothing. I get no listing of files.

```
opendir(Dir, $mydir);
while ($file = readdir(Dir)){
$file = grep  !/^\./  ,readdir Dir;
 print "$file\n";
```

I don't think I'm using the  regular expression correctly.
I don't want to use an array cause the array doesn't format the list correctly.

Comment: The modern best practice when working with file or directory handles is to use lexical handles with error checking: `opendir my $dh, $mydir or die $!`

Answer (score 4):

You can either iterate over directory entries using a loop, or read all the entries in the directory at once:

```
while (my $file = readdir(Dir)) {
    print "$file\n" if $file !~ /^\./;
}
```

or

```
my @files = grep { !/^\./  } readdir Dir;
```

See [`perldoc -f readdir`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir.html).

Answer (score 3):

You're calling readdir() twice in a loop. Don't.

Comment: DOH! Thanks I didn't realize that was a no-no.

Comment: You are also calling `grep` in scalar context. `$file` will just contain the number of matches from the `grep` call (i.e., the number of files that don't match `/^\./`)

Answer (score 1):

or like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl -w
use strict;

opendir my $dh, '.';
print map {$_."\n"} grep {!/^\./} readdir($dh);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use glob:

```
my @files = glob( "$mydir/*" );
print "@files\n";
```

See `perldoc -f glob` for details.

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($file = readdir(Dir))
{
    print "\n$file" if ( grep !/^\./, $file );
}
```

OR you can use a regualr expression :

```
while ($file = readdir(Dir))
{
    print "\n$file" unless ( $file =~ /^\./ );
}
```